# If $u$ is a positive harmonic function on an open set $V$ that vanishes on $V^c$, then $u$ is subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading the proof of the uniformization theorem from a [pdf](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Erobbin/951dir/uniformization.pdf) by Joel W. Robbin. On page 5, there's a corollary about subharmonic functions. My question is about proposition (iv):

*"If $u: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, positive and harmonic on an open set $V$, and vanishes on $X \setminus V$, then $u$ is subharmonic on $X$."*

But I think the proof has a problem in its last statement. The maximum principle states that a "nonconstant" subharmonic function doesn't assume its maximum but in the last statement of the proof, this case is ignored.

Is this proof correct? Or at least, Is this proposition correct?

Comment: If $u-v$ is constant then $u$ is harmonic, hence subharmonic. So wlog $u-v$ is not constant...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, $u$ will be harmonic but on $V$, not $X$. I think that in the last three lines of the proof, there are some typos in _"If $p \not\in X$..."_ and _"If $p \in X$..."_. The corrects are "If $p \not\in V...$" and "If $p \in V$...".

Comment: The proposition is trivial since subharmonicity is equivalent to the sub average property (the value at a point is less or equal than the average values on small circles around) and since $V$ is open that automatically happens there as $u$ is given subharmonic there, while on the complement the average is non negative while $u$ is zero

Comment: @Conrad Yes! that's correct and obvious from your viewpoint. Thanks. :)

Comment: Happy to be of help